Joomla 4 / 5 - Custom Field Plugin
I'm trying to update my Ajax based FolderList Fields Plugin (to select a Folder) for Joomla 4/5. All looks fine but the field does not get rendered correctly in the Article Fields Section - it looks like its not getting found somehow.
I'm following the new namespacing directives for this plugin. Because i don't know what code parts to post here see the Github Repo here: GitHub Repo
The field got rendered correctly in the plugin settings itself, the field params too but not the effective "Custom Field" itself when creating a new field of type nxdfolderlist. For example in the Article > Fields there will only a Text field been rendered.

Any input is welcome.

You need to register namespace for field class lookup:
\Joomla\CMS\Form\FormHelper::addFieldPrefix('NXD\\Plugin\\Fields\\NXDFolderList\\Field');

And also fix capitalization of field type. It is automatically derived from plugin element which is standardized as lowercase but your field class name is NXDFolderListField:
 $fieldNode->setAttribute('type', 'NXDFolderList');


To complete your answer - I've added addFieldPrefix into provider.php & fixed capitlaization in the onCustomfieldsPrepareDom Method - as mentioned and its working now.

Adding the prefix should be done in the event listener too. It does work in the service provider but it's just an unnecessary waste of resources.
